# How to set up openvpn on Mikrotik RouterOS 5.26

Tags: networking, openvpn, mikrotik-routeros

I have an OpenVPN connection that works well between an Ubuntu client and a Debian server.
I want to replace the Ubuntu client with a Mikrotik router equipped with RouterOS 5.26. In order to do that I have connected to the router through SSH and realized that the shell is very different from my usual bash. So I will learn that, but, in the meantime I need help in setting up the openvpn. I have successfully imported the certificates already in the router with scp and the /certificate command. Now I have the .conf file for openvpn but I have no idea what to do with it.
Note: this connection goes through an http proxy and I'm not sure I can set that up with the web admin interface, that's why I'm doing this through ssh, because I have the conf file and know it works.

Comment: It looks like it's supported, with some limitations, in RouterOS 7: [help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/OpenVPN](https://help.mikrotik.com/docs/display/ROS/OpenVPN).

Answer (score 0):

1. RouterOS only support CpenVPN on TCP. (UDP transport not supported)
2. As far as I know, ovpn-client in RouterOS cant support HTTP proxy.

   (In ROS, AFAIK, only SSTP-client can pass over http proxy.)

Comment: I know about 1, and it's ok since http proxy uses tcp and not udp. About 2, do you have any source? Anyway what I need is a way to try my conf file, then I can tell immediately if http proxy is supported or not. Thanks.

Comment: I know sstp-client has special options for http proxy. ovpn-client dont.
It can be checked in cli help
/interface ovpn-client add ?
/interface sstp-client add ?
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/SSTP#Properties
http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Interface/OVPN#Properties

It 90% enshure me in (2)

Comment: Try ask Mikrotik Support to add http proxy support to openvpn. Or generic tcp over https tunnel. But ovpn look abandoned by mikrotik.

Comment: I have control over the vpn server so I can switch from openvpn to something else if you recommend anything that can pass through an http proxy.

Comment: I don't found sstp server for linux. It strange, may be I don't make enough effort. You know one? In ROS, AFAIK, only SSTP-client can pass over http proxy.